# Partial search with LIKE and JSON object

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to use a partial search in my `WHERE` clause from a `JSON` filter. I'm passing a `,` delimited string and want to separate that in use in the where statement.

For example:

A sample table:

```
create table NewTable
(
   Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   SomeObject varchar(20),
   SomeText varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO NewTable(SomeObject, SomeText)values ('hello', 'test1')
INSERT INTO NewTable(SomeObject, SomeText)values ('yellow', 'test2')
INSERT INTO NewTable(SomeObject, SomeText)values ('test1', 'test1')
```

Here's the filter that's getting passed:

```
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Filter=N'{
  "SomeObject": "ello,yel"
}'
```

And I'm trying to select everything from the table that has `'%ello%'` or `'%yel%'`

```
select * from newtable pm
where 
(pm.SomeObject IS NULL AND JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.SomeObject') IS NULL OR pm.SomeObject LIKE '%' + (select value from string_split(ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.SomeObject'),pm.SomeObject), ',')) + '%')
```

This query works partially. I have many instances that the `subquery` will return more than 1 row. I can switch to use `IN` clause, but I wouldn't be able to perform partial search. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

EDIT:

Based on the above filter, the output should return all the rows that has `ello` or `yel` in the `SomeObject` column. So in this example, should return row 1 and 2.

Comment: if you can share the input sample and desired output that would make it a little more clear.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja, I added more descripion.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja, what do you mean?

Comment: what is the current output you are getting

Comment: It throws an error since `subquery is returning more than 1 row.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may try with this:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE NewTable
(
   Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   SomeObject varchar(20),
   SomeText varchar(20)
)
INSERT INTO NewTable(SomeObject, SomeText) VALUES ('hello', 'test1')
INSERT INTO NewTable(SomeObject, SomeText) VALUES ('yellow', 'test2')
INSERT INTO NewTable(SomeObject, SomeText) VALUES ('test1', 'test1')

-- JSON
DECLARE @Filter nvarchar(MAX)
SET @Filter = N'{
  "SomeObject": "ello,yel"
}'

-- Statement
SELECT pm.*
FROM NewTable pm
WHERE 
   -- 1. @Filter is null
   (ISJSON(@Filter) IS NULL) OR
   -- 2. $.SomeObject is empty text, @Filter = N'{"SomeObject": ""}'
   (JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.SomeObject') = N'') OR
   (JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.SomeObject') IS NULL) OR
   -- 3. Filter exists
   (
      (ISJSON(@Filter) IS NOT NULL) AND
      (JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.SomeObject') <> N'') AND
      (JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.SomeObject') IS NOT NULL) AND
      EXISTS (
         SELECT * 
         FROM STRING_SPLIT(JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.SomeObject'), ',') 
         WHERE pm.SomeObject LIKE CONCAT('%', [Value], '%')
      )
   )
```

Comment: your answer is almost working. I originally have this condition `pm.SomeObject IS NULL AND JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.SomeObject') IS NULL OR ...` in my code to return everything if the `filter` is not specified. But in your code, if the filter is empty it will return nothing. I tried to modify the code inside the `WHERE EXISTS` to `(pm.SomeObject IS NULL AND JSON_VALUE(@Filter, N'$.SomeObject') IS NULL OR pm.SomeObject LIKE CONCAT('%', [Value], '%'))` but it's still return nothing if no `filter` specified. Any suggestion on how to return everything if no filter specified? `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: @smr5 I've updated the answer with some additional `where` clauses. See if this helps. Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much! Can you edit your answer and add this `OR` statement `(JSON_VALUE(@Filter, '$.SomeObject') IS NULL) OR` in the second case? In case if I had the filter set as `SET @Filter=N'{}` it wouldn't return all the rows and it would simply get nothing. The above will take care of that scenario.

Comment: @smr5 Answer is edited. With this `OR` condition I've added another `AND` in 3rd case. Check if this works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use `OPENJSON` to parse the JSON, and then `STRING_SPLIT` to split the delimited list:

```
DECLARE @Filter nvarchar(MAX);

SET @Filter=N'{
  "SomeObject": "ello,yel"
}';
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT NT.Id,
           NT.SomeObject,
           NT.SomeText,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NT.ID ORDER BY SS.[Value]) AS RN
    FROM dbo.NewTable NT
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(@Filter) OJ
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(OJ.[value], ',') SS
    WHERE NT.SomeObject LIKE '%' + SS.[value] + '%')
SELECT Id,
       SomeObject,
       SomeText
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

As, however, rows could be matched multiple times (`'Yellow'` contains both the string `'yel'` and `'ello'`), you also need a CTE to ensure only 1 row per `Id` is returned.

Comment: +1 for getting me the correct output. However, unfortunately, I'm not able to easily implement this into my larger query.  The output basically uses this filter to filter the data and then return the result as json object. I have thought about splitting json and putting it into cte table and joining the cte back my end result, but that's still has issues.

Comment: Sounds like we've only been given a small piece of a much larger picture. I suggest posted the real problem in your question here @smr5 if you want an answer that addresses your full problem. What the information we have, this answer address it.

Comment: you're right. I didn't expect this to be this complicated. All I wanted to know is `How to build an OR statement in my WHERE clause` from a `,` separated string, since the subquery chokes on more than one result.  I guess there's no simple way.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will match each string like `hello` as seperate in a concatenated regex like `%[hello]%[yellow]%`

```
  select * from newtable pm
    where 
   (pm.SomeObject IS NULL AND 
  JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.SomeObject') IS NULL 
    OR pm.SomeObject  LIKE '%[' + select 
  REPLACE
    (JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.SomeObject')
            ,',',']%['  ) + ']%' 
     )
```

Comment: It's returning no results.

Comment: try to debug output in the select itself see what is the output with replace did you remove the select before replace query

Comment: You get this from the `REPLACE` `elloyel%` for all rows.

Comment: where is the starting `%` should be like `%elloyel%`

Comment: That's the output I get from this select. `select REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.SomeObject'),',','')+'%'  from newtable`

Comment: can try replacing `,` with `%` as well coz now whats happening is the full concated string elloyel should be there in `hello` `yellow` etc which hasnt be the case till now thats y the output is 0 records. use `select REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.SomeObject'),',','%') `. hope after this it works coz now the output will be ` %ello%yel% ` that means hello n yellow should be matched

Comment: use this regex format `LIKE '%[' + select REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.SomeObject'),',',']%[') + ']%' `

Comment: +1 for your effort on helping me. You're close, but still not correct. First, you're missing `(` before `SELECT` and `)` at the end. But the issue here is if you provide only one value in the filter like `"SomeObject": "test"` it returns all rows. And if no filter specified, the first condition should return everything, but it's not.